# "Have" Vs "Has" when using with name of a team

Tags: collective-nouns

Which of the two sentences are grammatically correct?

> Ferrari **has** been struggling this season.

Or

> Ferrari **have** been struggling this season.

According to my understanding, 'has' is what I should use because 'Ferrari' is a name of a team. But, I've been listening to a lot of YouTubers using 'Have'. One of such examples is [Charles Leclerc Escapes Penalty And MORE | Jolyon Palmer On The 2019 Italian Grand Prix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-331N72Iu0&t=964). At 16:04, he says

> Ferrari, since the summer break, **have** hit hard.

I'm not a native English speaker. Am I missing something?

P.S: Is it something to do with collective-nouns? It's one topic I have a difficult time with. If so, I don't want you to spoon-feed me the entire concept. You can post a link where I can read it and understand it myself.

Comment: I believe there's a US/UK difference here

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a *Grand Prix* fan, but I trust you and take that Ferrari is a team. Now, based on that, here is the answer.

Certain words take a plural verb. For example -data and media.

> The media have been pretty partial to the current government.

Now, some collective nouns such as *team, audience, and government* could be singular or plural depending on the context. If you consider them as a single group, you use a *singular verb* and if as a collection of individuals, a *plural* form.

> The ***team has*** done a fantastic job this financial year ~ considering the team as *one*

But,

> The ***team have*** some dispute within ~ considering a collection of individuals

Comment: But, how do we decide which one to consider? Is there a rule or is it entirely up to the speaker?

Comment: As I said, it depends on both the *author* and *context.* Nobody will hold you for having *England have won the World Cup."